# How can update the WKInterfaceLabel in the not shown controllers use page based segue

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2, wkinterfacecontroller

in my application for watchos 2 when I update data are updated only in the controller which shown. If I update label in willActivate() - text changes with a delay. How  can update the WKInterfaceLabel in the not shown controllers use page based? The method WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames is not suitable

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used WatchKit specifically.

But to my understanding the `willActivate()` method may be too late in the lifecycle for you. Have you tried looking at changing the text in earlier methods such as the `init()` one?

I took a quick glance at the [WatchKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide).

Comment: In a page-based interface, all interface controllers are initialized up front but only the first one is displayed initially...

Comment: if you somehow have a reference to the view, you may be able to update the property while on another page

Comment: doing so, but for some reason is not updated until you can see the screen

Comment: Ah, there may be an other way. But there is a good chance it's because of WatchKit its limitations